# conditional table view cell display

Tags: ios, tableview, afnetworking

I want to display a tableview cell only if my AFNetworking request returns a json object as true. In this example I need place = "Store" to be true in order to display a table view which displays only stores.

the place = "Store" json is returned as part of my location_results array in the following request and I store it with `self.place = [dictionary objectForKey:@"place"];`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // LoadLocations

  [[LocationApiClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"locations.json" parameters:nil                                     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
    NSMutableArray *location_results = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id locationDictionary in response) {
        Location *location = [[Location alloc] initWithDictionary:locationDictionary];
        [location_results addObject:location];

    }
    self.location_results = location_results;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
                                    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"Error fetching locations!");
                                        NSLog(@"%@", error);

                                    }];
```

I know I need to start by changing

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.location_results.count;
}
```

but not sure how.

Then I should be able to add a conditional statement to

```
- (LocationCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"LocationCell";
```

but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have working code for all results, then working code for a subset of the results is simple.  Replace references to `self.location_results`, with `[self filteredLocationResults]`, implemented like this:

```
- (NSArray *)filteredLocationResults {

    return [self.location_results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K like %@)". @"place" ,@"Store"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the "Store" items into the table's data source:

```
for (id locationDictionary in response) {
    Location *location = [[Location alloc] initWithDictionary:locationDictionary];
    if([[location objectForKey:@"place"] isEqualToString:@"Store"]) // Add this line
        [location_results addObject:location];

}
```

Comment: This seems like it should work but I got an error no visible @interface declares selector objectforkey. I'm assuming there is something missing in my code that you expected for this to work.

Comment: Well, this assumes (based on your question) that Location is based on NSDictionary.  If not, then you need to check the place value of the location object...